# Should .htaccess commands be case sensitive?

Tags: .htaccess

I have seen many tutorials on [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess). Different people write differently.
You can find variations of casing:

```
rewriteengine on
RewriteEntgine on
Rewritengine On
```

It seems all of those are working fine.

1. Is there a reason for casing [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess) commands?
2. Is it possible for a command to fail due to wrong casing?

Comment: BestPractices suggest you RTFM :) and do abide by CaseSensitivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache documentation suggests that the directives are not case-sensitive, but the argument may be. I would recommend you stick to the format declared in the official documentation to avoid possible confusion and/or failure.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html#syntax
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteEngine